# Import Contacts and related records together

Tags: master-detail, import, many-to-many

Our schema is structured so that Contacts (alumni) can be linked to multiple Accounts (schools) using a custom object, which itself contains a few other fields. We also have other custom objects with master-detail links to Contact (eg. employment history entries).

We want to be able to upload data gathered from a form or survey (with only a simplified subset of what we can store), which would come (after scanning/data entry) as a CSV file. Of course not all the information is to be stored in the Contact object!

Tools such as dataloader.io allow external ID lookups, ie. whoever generates the CSV file doesn't need to know the long Salesforce IDs of the schools. What it doesn't seem to do is create the related records.

Are there any data upload tools out there, that once configured, would be usable by the layperson (non-techie, no relational database expertise), that would insert the related many-many and history records as well as the Contact?

Comment: What I want to avoid is adding extra fields on Contact that, when filled, would fire a trigger to create the related record from the information in those fields. We had a hack like that in our previous CRM, and it grew into people relying on the bogus fields, and there were issues about keeping them in sync.

Comment: Talend Open Studio is what my company uses for similar data loads.

Comment: Are you looking for multi-use import ability, or one-time migration?

Comment: Regular use, by non-tech users once it has been configured. Must require only one upload action by the user- ie *not* upload the contacts, extract their IDs, then upload the links to their schools, then upload the employment history entries.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the new Composite API
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite.htm

It looks like Informatica (I don't work for them, have never used this product) have a product that might help https://network.informatica.com/thread/51847

Check other providers as well (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?keywords=integration)

Answer (score 0):

My top idea for this at the moment is to create another custom object as a "staging area" for the upload, with the same structure as the CSV file. Processing it would then be done in custom batch Apex, which the user would kick off (eg. with a button).

Comment: This could be added with question itself.